# How to generate junit output with nosetests?

Tags: junit, xunit, nosetests

I have some tests I would like to run with `nosetests` and generate `junit xml` results. As far as I know, this is not possible by the default installation of nosetests, as it only produced `xunit` xml files.

However, nose plugins exist which can do various things, among them a [code snippet](http://nose-devs.github.io/nose2/_modules/nose2/plugins/junitxml.html) to be use to create `junit` xml output.

My questions:

- What are the differences between `junit` and `xunit` xml results? Are they basically different and incompatible?
- How to install or use the junitxml plugin code in the link I mentioned above? Maybe there is a different way to create junit output?

Comment: xunit is junit format https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUnit

Answer (score 3):

Nose supports xunit natively, now.

> nose [supports](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/xunit.html) xunit output with built-in plugin, just try --with-xunit

~ From [Oleksiy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/255365/oleksiy), https://stackoverflow.com/a/20750012/311901

Answer (score 1):

This is a nose plugin; You can install it by

```
pip install NoseXUnit
```

Read the documentation for it here: http://nosexunit.sourceforge.net/. This will help you run the plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can get xUnit XML results using [`nosetests --with-xunit`](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/xunit.html).

JUnit XML is basically the same thing as xUnit XML. The letter before `Unit` stands for the programming language being tested. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUnit:

> xUnit is the collective name for several unit testing frameworks that derive their structure and functionality from Smalltalk's SUnit. (…) The names of many of these frameworks are a variation on "SUnit," usually replacing the "S" with the first letter (or letters) in the name of their intended language ("JUnit" for Java, "RUnit" for R, etc.). These frameworks and their common architecture are collectively known as "xUnit".

You cannot get true JUnit XML reports since you are not testing Java but Python with `nosetests`. However, JUnit and xUnit XML results should be mostly compatible. The [Nosetests Xunit documentation](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/xunit.html) claims:

> This plugin provides test results in the standard XUnit XML format.
>
> It’s designed for the Jenkins (previously Hudson) continuous build system, but will probably work for anything else that understands an XUnit-formatted XML representation of test results.

…and later (emphasis mine):

> In a Jenkins builder, tick the box named “Publish **JUnit** test result report”…