# Problems installing NoseXUnit

Tags: python-2.7, pip, nose, xunit, nosetests

I tried to install NoseXUnit using pip. Trying to run nosetests with it ends with the following error message:

```
# nosetests --with-nosexunit
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.0-py2.7.egg/nose/plugins/manager.py:395: RuntimeWarning: Unable to load plugin nosexunit = nosexunit.plugin:NoseXUnit: (coverage 3.7.1 (/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('coverage==2.85'))
  RuntimeWarning)
Usage: nosetests [options]

nosetests: error: no such option: --with-nosexunit
```

So it seems like there's a problem with "coverage" version - I have version 3.7.1 and for some reason it requires 2.85:

```
# nosetests --help | grep -i nosex
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.0-py2.7.egg/nose/plugins/manager.py:395: RuntimeWarning: Unable to load plugin nosexunit = nosexunit.plugin:NoseXUnit: (coverage 3.7.1 (/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('coverage==2.85'))
  RuntimeWarning)
```

Is that issue? Also, `pip install coverage==2.85` doesn't work.

What can I do in order to fix nose to work with NoseXUnit?

Any alternative for xml based reports framework is also welcomed (jenkins purposes).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Nose & NoseXUnit on a Python package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083102/using-nose-nosexunit-on-a-python-package)

Answer (score 0):

nose [supports](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/xunit.html) xunit output with built-in plugin, just try `--with-xunit`